# IE 8 's Error: Message: Expected '}'

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, internet-explorer-8

IE8 Error :

```
Message: Expected '}'

Line: 59
```

Line: 59  where second example is located ----- >   ( $magicLineTwo.stop().animate({  )

```
    $("#example-two li").find("a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();
        $magicLineTwo.stop().animate({         
            left: leftPos,         
            width: newWidth
            backgroundColor: $el.attr("rel")
        });
```

The entire javascript code can be found here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uB5n/)

I would appreciate if someone can help me, for weeks been stuck on this.

Comment: Why would any web developer use IE8? O_o

Comment: using all browsers,just to make sure they all function properly is better, but this yellow error icon on IE8 is a major problem :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you missed a comma in here:

```
    left: leftPos,
    width: newWidth
    backgroundColor: $el.attr("rel")
```

It should look like this:

```
    left: leftPos,
    width: newWidth,
    backgroundColor: $el.attr("rel")
```

Comment: Yes, I meant a comma, thanks :) I updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Put a **comma** here:

```
left: leftPos,
width: newWidth
               ^
backgroundColor: $el.attr("rel")
```

Comment: the moment I put the comma I get another error in IE8,   'position().left' is null or not an object ------------> $magicLineTwo

Comment: The problem is, I am unable to test it as I have IE 10 with me and it works perfectly in all the modes. `:(`

Comment: Nopes... No errors... :(